# Can send function return 0 using BSD socket in blocking mode?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock

When calling send function, if there is no space in socket buffer for entire message, there will be stored as much bytes as there is space and that amount will be returned.
If there is no space at all, function will block until there is at least 1 byte of space available, store it and return stored amount.

Are above sentences true?

Is there situation when send will return 0 bytes?(Except when SNDTIMEO is set and time expires)

Answer (score 1):

> When calling send function, if there is no space in socket buffer for entire message, there will be stored as much bytes as there is space and that amount will be returned. If there is no space at all, function will block until there is at least 1 byte of space available, store it and return stored amount.
>
> Are above sentences true?

No. There was a discussion about this some years ago on news:comp.protocols.tcp-ip where all the implementors gather, and there was a consensus that Posix requires not only that it can't return zero, it can't return less than the value of the `length` parameter, in blocking mode.

> Is there situation when send will return 0 bytes?(Except when SNDTIMEO is set and time expires)

Yes, *if and only if* the `length` parameter supplied is zero.

NB if `SO_SNDTIMEO` is set to a non-zero value and the timeout expires, `send()` won't return zero: it will return -1 with `errno` equal to `EAGAIN/EWOULBLOCK,` if no bytes were transferred.